# Conversão de array com json_encode PHP

Tags: php, json

Opa, alguém sabe porque quando eu faço isso:

```
json_encode(array("0" => 0));
```

Retorna isso: `[0]`

Em vez disso: `{"0":0}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O PHP deteta automáticamente se estás a usar chaves numéricas e converte numa array.

Se quiseres mesmo um objeto podes usar [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) no segundo argumento (PHP 5.3+), opcional do `json_encode`. (exemplo: https://ideone.com/kFftSu)

Repara que se juntares outro elemento a essa array, sem chave numérica, o `json_encode` já lê como objeto.

**Exemplo** (https://ideone.com/yyrya4):

```
echo json_encode(array("0" => 0, "foo" => "bar"));
// dá:
{"0":0,"foo":"bar"}
```